# DOMContentLoaded will be fired twice on my page

Tags: javascript

In my page at http://www.sybase-recovery.com/outlook-repair/, I write a very simple script theme1.js at http://www.sybase-recovery.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/js/theme1.js, as below:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var b = 1;
});
```

But during the debug, I find DOMContentLoaded event will be fired twice when pressing Ctrl + F5 to load the page.

I try to search online, and find two results:

1. [DOMContentLoaded event firing twice for a single page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355344/domcontentloaded-event-firing-twice-for-a-single-page-load), which said AVG add-on causes the issue, but I do not have AVG add-on installed.
2. http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1590225, which provides a solution at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Detecting_page_load, but the link is broken.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your page has an iframe

```
<iframe width="100%" height="800px" src="http://www.sybase-recovery.com/support/documentation/outlook-repair/"></iframe>
```

It also includes the same theme1.js file

Comment: Thank you. I see. In the live site, the page put in iframe does not include theme1.js, but in my current test site, I do not include that page, which lead to a 404 not found error page, which contains theme1.js